# ListBox DrawItem HotLight State in the OwnerDraw mode?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, ownerdrawn

I'm using `OwnerDrawFixed` as a DrawMode for the custom ListBox control in my WinForms app.

I want to repaint the background (or do some other action) of the ListBoxItem when the user hovers over the listbox item, that is, at the MouseMove...

`DrawItemState.HotLight` never works for the ListBox, so i wonder how to emulate it, how to workaround this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It took me only two years to find the answer for you, but here it is:

The DrawItemState.HotLight only applies to owner drawn menus, not the listbox.  For the ListBox, you have to keep track of the item yourself:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private int _MouseIndex = -1;

  public Form1()
  { InitializeComponent(); }

  private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
  {
    Brush textBrush = SystemBrushes.WindowText;

    if (e.Index > -1)
    {
      if (e.Index == _MouseIndex)
      {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.HotTrack, e.Bounds);
        textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
      }
      else
      {
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds);
          textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
        }
        else
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
      }
      e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, textBrush, e.Bounds.Left + 2, e.Bounds.Top);
    }
  }

  private void listBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (index != _MouseIndex)
    {
      _MouseIndex = index;
      listBox1.Invalidate();
    }
  }

  private void listBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (_MouseIndex > -1)
    {
      _MouseIndex = -1;
      listBox1.Invalidate();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, 2 years later you helped me too! ;) Nice, simple way for 'hot tracking' in a listbox...thanks!

Comment: And LarsTech will help many for many years to come...I was looking for a similar answer and found it here. Thanks.

Comment: How can this be done for a combobox? Combobox doesn't have IndexFromPoint.

Comment: @AdamBruss The mouse events only report on the TextBox part of the ComboBox, too.  Shouldn't really be an issue though with a ComboBox because there the DrawItemState.Selected is being called on every mouse movement.  Just ignore the `MouseIndex` part of the code.  For the ComboBox, the DrawItemState.Selected is essentially the same thing as the hot index.  To test, I changed my `FillRectangle` to use a red brush and it painted every item red my mouse was hovering over.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will just weigh your code down; just try this:

```
If e.State And DrawItemState.Selected Then
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.HotTrack, e.Bounds)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(drv, Me.Font, SystemBrushes.HighlightText, e.Bounds.X + 18, e.Bounds.Y + 1)
                Else
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(drv, Me.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, e.Bounds.X + 18, e.Bounds.Y + 1)
End If
```

This operation: `e.State And DrawItemState.Selected` verifies the item is hovered. No need to put a whole pack of code just to know what item is hovered.

Comment: Your solution doesn't actually address the issue the OP was asking about.