# Winforms - Listbox - MouseHover - Item Color

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

How to change an item's color when focusing on it in the *winforms* `listbox`?

I tried with the `MouseHover` event of the `listbox`. But nothing happens.

```
private void lstNumbers_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point point = lstNumbers.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

    int index = lstNumbers.IndexFromPoint(point);
    if (index < 0) return;

    lstNumbers.GetItemRectangle(index).Inflate(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you think is anything happening wrt to coloring?? Also: Hover and Focus are not the same thing by default.. Finally: Hover is not working as you may expect: It will not fire again when you move the mouse inside a control. Maybe the MouseMove wil help you better. But I don't relly know in what..?

Comment: @TaW, Is there any solution ? Tried with the `MouseMove` also and nothing happens.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1316027/292411 for a solution which uses the `DrawMode` property to override painting the items.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, Thank You, I followed that question and solved my problem.

Comment: 'Tried with the MouseMove also and nothing happens.' Of course. There is nothing in your code to 'happen'..

Comment: @TaW, 'Maybe the MouseMove wil help you better'. No, You are wrong. We need to use `DrawItem`, `MouseLeave` events. MouseMove alone won't help in this case. See my _answer_ below for the reference.

Comment: Maybe you now get what you want but then it is not what you have asked. If I was wrong, it was because I couldn't read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6951157/3976144).

We need to keep track of the item,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private int _MouseIndex = -1;

  public Form1()
  { InitializeComponent(); }

  private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
  {
    Brush textBrush = SystemBrushes.WindowText;

    if (e.Index > -1)
    {
      if (e.Index == _MouseIndex)
      {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.HotTrack, e.Bounds);
        textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
      }
      else
      {
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds);
          textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
        }
        else
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
      }
      e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, textBrush, e.Bounds.Left + 2, e.Bounds.Top);
    }
  }

  private void listBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if (index != _MouseIndex)
    {
      _MouseIndex = index;
      listBox1.Invalidate();
    }
  }

  private void listBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (_MouseIndex > -1)
    {
      _MouseIndex = -1;
      listBox1.Invalidate();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem maybe that your not actually changing the colour of the item your hovering over:

```
lstNumbers.GetItemRectangle(index).Inflate(1, 2); //This is trying to inflate the item
```

You need to do something to change the color.

Also there is the `ItemMouseHover` event which you can utilise. Something like:

```
private void lstNumbers_ItemMouseHover(object sender, ListViewItemMouseHoverEventArgs e)
{
      e.Item.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: **QUESTION IS ABOUT** `WINFORMS`