# how to highlight the "hovered" item when dragging the item inside listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, listbox

I would like to highlight the hovered item when dragging the item inside `ListBox`

I find one related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316027/listbox-drawitem-hotlight-state-in-the-ownerdraw-mode), but when mouse is pressed, the `MouseMove` and `MouseLeave` event stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the mouse is captured by another control, mouse event's like `MouseMove` will not raise for the drop target control.

Regardless of the mouse capture, you always can find the hot index using the following code:

```
var index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(listBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
```

If the mouse enter/move/leave events during the drag is important for you, use drag events `DragEnter`, `DragOver` and `DragLeave` events.

For example, to get the index of the item under the mouse pointer when the mouse is dragging over the target listbox, you can handle `DragOver`:

```
private void listBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(listBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reza! I use your function together with Invalidate and drawitem. It works well!